# converting string to integer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am reading some values from an xml file using JavaScript. Since it is a string, i need to convert it to integer and perform some calculations.

For reading the data from XML file I use this code:

```
var pop = JSON.stringify(feature.attributes.Total_Pop.value);
```

which works fine. later I use the following code to convert it to integer:

```
var popint = parseInt(pop);
```

This also works fine. But later when I use it to do some math, it returns NAN.

the code I use for Math operation is:

```
var pop6 = Math.ceil(popint / 30);
```

What am I doing wrong? any suggestions?

Comment: That depends on what the string is, but perhaps you could simply `parseInt(popint, 10) / 30`. Ref. [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: Try giving the parseInt function a base value, and you might want to make it a float, not everything /30 is a whole number.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? `console.log( popint ); console.log( typeof popint );`?

Comment: If you are getting `NaN` that means the string parsed was not actually an integer

Comment: + there's not enough information here to give an answer; obviously if `popint = parseInt( pop )` "works fine" (i.e. is an integer) then `Math.ceil( popint / 30 )` can't be NaN unless the value of `popint` has changed somewhere in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stringify -- just use `var pop = feature.attributes.Total_Pop.value;`.  Calling JSON.stringify wraps the string in extra quotation marks.

```
var pop = "123";                    // "123"
var popint = parseInt(pop);         // 123
```

Vs:

```
var pop = JSON.stringify("123");    // ""123""
var popint = parseInt(pop);         // NaN
```